# Why I can't move divs to the very left top or right corner?

Tags: html, css

I can't move my divs to the very left or very right top. I am new to the HTML and CSS, and trying to solve it like 2 hours on my own.

I think its about positioning(absolute, relative,..), but I'm not sure.

---

#### Code :

```css
#stajl ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#stajl ul li:hover a {
    background-color: red;
}
#stajl ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#stajl ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
#stajl ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -144px;
}
#stajl ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#stajl ul ul li {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    width: 352px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stajl">
    <ul>
         <li>
             <a href="#">Home Page </a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="#">Services <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#">Trades </a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#">Exchanges </a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#">Business to Business </a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="#">About </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Contact </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

#### Screenshot :

[image]

Big thanks to the Admin/Mod who edited this for me.

Comment: the css by itself is not very useful - you need to show the html it applies to.

Comment: Thanks ! I've edited it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the space at the top left BEFORE your menu, you should do this :

- Add a `padding` of 0 to `#stajl ul`
- Re-adjust your `margin` for `#stajl ul ul`

---

To remove the spaces between your `li` elements, you should do this :

- Make `block` the display value for `#stajl ul li`
- Add `float : left` to `#stajl ul li`

---

### Result :

```css
#stajl ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding : 0;
}

#stajl ul li:hover a {
    background-color: red;
}

#stajl ul li {
    display: block;
    float : left;
}

#stajl ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

#stajl ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -104px;
}

#stajl ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#stajl ul ul li {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    width: 352px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stajl">
    <ul>
         <li>
             <a href="#">Home Page </a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="#">Services <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#">Trades </a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#">Exchanges </a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#">Business to Business </a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="#">About </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Contact </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I found solution, but your solution also worked! 
Thanks a lot for so many answers in so short time ! :) How many questions can I ask per day?

Comment: @Vuks : I'm glad you appreciate the effort. I made one more change to the code, to fix the spaces between your `li` elements. If you don't want the spaces, you should use `display : block` and `float : left` instead of `display : inline-block`.

Comment: I tried you code also and I couldn't see any difference. Maybe I am blind hehe
Thanks though !

Comment: @Vuks : For the effect WITH `display : block` & `float : left`, see http://jsfiddle.net/Sb2w4/45/. For the effect WITHOUT `display : block` & `float : left`, see http://jsfiddle.net/Sb2w4/46/. Open them both in different tabs to compare results ;-)

Comment: Ouu Thanks for that, but I am changing it in HTML, putting <li> afer </li> in the same line and then starting <a> in new line.
Anyways, I am thankful for that, because I've learnt now second way of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

did you try the commands top:/left:
for the very left I would do `ļeft:0px;` for the right likewise `right:0px`
If you want it to be at the very top then you have to add `top:0px`or `bottom:0px`for the very bottom of the page
in edition of your question I would suggest :

```
#stajl div {
   position: absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Tried to put it in "#stajl ul" and "#stajl ul li" but nothing changed.

Thanks anyways.

Comment: maybe if you do that with the div tag, like I edited my answer above?

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your css.

```
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

note that browser has default margin, padding settings.

in my case (chrome)
`body` has 8px margin.
`ul` has 40px left padding.

as a result, your item positioned to down, right

Comment: This one helped, but there's still a little white space in there. Maybe that's normal.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the browser default margin and padding is messing with your code. Add a CSS reset:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

That fixed it for me.

When using CSS, you probably want to use a more advanced reset. This is only good for margins and padding, some browser-created properties will still screw up your code if you're not careful.

Comment: This one helped, but there's still a little white space in there. Maybe that's normal.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: White space in the navbar itself, or out? If inner, that's normal inline-block behavior, just add a background to the `ul` and make the `a`s as large as the `li`s